# Commenting out JS gives dev console error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to comment out a block of code in my site's main.js file, since it makes my sticky header jump in a funny way upon scrolling.

When I comment out the sticky header section, it fixes the jumpy header issue.

However, it also throws the following error in Firefox or Chrome developer console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Here is the original unedited code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    // Sticky Header
    if ($('body').hasClass('sticky-header')) {
        var header = $('#sp-header');

        if($('#sp-header').length) {
            var headerHeight = header.outerHeight();
            var stickyHeaderTop = header.offset().top;
            var stickyHeader = function () {
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                if (scrollTop > stickyHeaderTop) {
                    header.addClass('header-sticky');
                } else {
                    if (header.hasClass('header-sticky')) {
                        header.removeClass('header-sticky');
                    }
                }
            };
            stickyHeader();
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                stickyHeader();
            });
        }

        if ($('body').hasClass('layout-boxed')) {
            var windowWidth = header.parent().outerWidth();
            header.css({"max-width": windowWidth, "left": "auto"});
        }
    }


    // go to top
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.sp-scroll-up').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.sp-scroll-up').fadeOut(400);
        }
    });

    $('.sp-scroll-up').click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 600);
        return false;
    });

    // Preloader
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        $('.sp-preloader').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

    //mega menu
    $('.sp-megamenu-wrapper').parent().parent().css('position', 'static').parent().css('position', 'relative');
    $('.sp-menu-full').each(function () {
        $(this).parent().addClass('menu-justify');
    });

    // Offcanvs
    $('#offcanvas-toggler').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.offcanvas-init').addClass('offcanvas-active');
    });

    $('.close-offcanvas, .offcanvas-overlay').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.offcanvas-init').removeClass('offcanvas-active');
    });
    
    $(document).on('click', '.offcanvas-inner .menu-toggler', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.menu-parent').toggleClass('menu-parent-open').find('>.menu-child').slideToggle(400);
    });

    //Tooltip
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

    // Article Ajax voting
    $('.article-ratings .rating-star').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $parent = $(this).closest('.article-ratings');

        var request = {
            'option': 'com_ajax',
            'template': template,
            'action': 'rating',
            'rating': $(this).data('number'),
            'article_id': $parent.data('id'),
            'format': 'json'
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: request,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $parent.find('.fa-spinner').show();
            },
            success: function (response) {
                var data = $.parseJSON(response);
                $parent.find('.ratings-count').text(data.message);
                $parent.find('.fa-spinner').hide();

                if(data.status)
                {
                    $parent.find('.rating-symbol').html(data.ratings)
                }

                setTimeout(function(){
                    $parent.find('.ratings-count').text('(' + data.rating_count + ')')
                }, 3000);
            }
        });
    });

    //  Cookie consent
    $('.sp-cookie-allow').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();               
        document.cookie = "spcookie_status=ok" + expires + "; path=/";

        $(this).closest('.sp-cookie-consent').fadeOut();
    });

    $(".btn-group label:not(.active)").click(function()
        {
            var label = $(this);
            var input = $('#' + label.attr('for'));
            
            if (!input.prop('checked')) {
                label.closest('.btn-group').find("label").removeClass('active btn-success btn-danger btn-primary');
                if (input.val() === '') {
                    label.addClass('active btn-primary');
                } else if (input.val() == 0) {
                    label.addClass('active btn-danger');
                } else {
                    label.addClass('active btn-success');
                }
                input.prop('checked', true);
                input.trigger('change');
            }
            var parent = $(this).parents('#attrib-helix_ultimate_blog_options'); 
            if( parent ){ 
                showCategoryItems( parent, input.val() )
            }
        });
        $(".btn-group input[checked=checked]").each(function()
        {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $("label[for=" + $(this).attr('id') + "]").addClass('active btn btn-primary');
            } else if ($(this).val() == 0) {
                $("label[for=" + $(this).attr('id') + "]").addClass('active btn btn-danger');
            } else {
                $("label[for=" + $(this).attr('id') + "]").addClass('active btn btn-success');
            }
            var parent = $(this).parents('#attrib-helix_ultimate_blog_options'); 
            if( parent ){
                parent.find('*[data-showon]').each( function() {
                    $(this).hide();
                })
            }
        });
        

        function showCategoryItems(parent, value){
            var controlGroup = parent.find('*[data-showon]'); 
            controlGroup.each( function() {
                var data = $(this).attr('data-showon')
                data = typeof data !== 'undefined' ? JSON.parse( data ) : []
                if( data.length > 0 ){
                    if(typeof data[0].values !== 'undefined' && data[0].values.includes( value )){
                        $(this).slideDown();
                    }else{
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        $(window).on('scroll', function(){
            var scrollBar = $(".sp-reading-progress-bar");
            if( scrollBar.length > 0 ){
                var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
                    d = $(document).height(),
                    c = $(window).height();
                var scrollPercent = (s / (d - c)) * 100;
                const postition = scrollBar.data('position')
                if( postition === 'top' ){
                    // var sticky = $('.header-sticky');
                    // if( sticky.length > 0 ){
                    //     sticky.css({ top: scrollBar.height() })
                    // }else{
                    //     sticky.css({ top: 0 })
                    // }
                }
                scrollBar.css({width: `${scrollPercent}%` })
            }
             
          })    

});
```

The portion I want to comment out is just the "sticky header" block.

I tried to do so like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    // Sticky Header
/*    if ($('body').hasClass('sticky-header')) {
        var header = $('#sp-header');

        if($('#sp-header').length) {
            var headerHeight = header.outerHeight();
            var stickyHeaderTop = header.offset().top;
            var stickyHeader = function () {
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                if (scrollTop > stickyHeaderTop) {
                    header.addClass('header-sticky');
                } else {
                    if (header.hasClass('header-sticky')) {
                        header.removeClass('header-sticky');
                    }
                }
            };
            stickyHeader();
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                stickyHeader();
            });
        }

        if ($('body').hasClass('layout-boxed')) {
            var windowWidth = header.parent().outerWidth();
            header.css({"max-width": windowWidth, "left": "auto"});
        }
    }
*/

    // go to top
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.sp-scroll-up').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.sp-scroll-up').fadeOut(400);
        }
    });

    $('.sp-scroll-up').click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 600);
        return false;
    });

    // Preloader
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        $('.sp-preloader').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

    //mega menu
    $('.sp-megamenu-wrapper').parent().parent().css('position', 'static').parent().css('position', 'relative');
    $('.sp-menu-full').each(function () {
        $(this).parent().addClass('menu-justify');
    });

    // Offcanvs
    $('#offcanvas-toggler').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.offcanvas-init').addClass('offcanvas-active');
    });

    $('.close-offcanvas, .offcanvas-overlay').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.offcanvas-init').removeClass('offcanvas-active');
    });
    
    $(document).on('click', '.offcanvas-inner .menu-toggler', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.menu-parent').toggleClass('menu-parent-open').find('>.menu-child').slideToggle(400);
    });

    //Tooltip
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

    // Article Ajax voting
    $('.article-ratings .rating-star').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $parent = $(this).closest('.article-ratings');

        var request = {
            'option': 'com_ajax',
            'template': template,
            'action': 'rating',
            'rating': $(this).data('number'),
            'article_id': $parent.data('id'),
            'format': 'json'
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: request,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $parent.find('.fa-spinner').show();
            },
            success: function (response) {
                var data = $.parseJSON(response);
                $parent.find('.ratings-count').text(data.message);
                $parent.find('.fa-spinner').hide();

                if(data.status)
                {
                    $parent.find('.rating-symbol').html(data.ratings)
                }

                setTimeout(function(){
                    $parent.find('.ratings-count').text('(' + data.rating_count + ')')
                }, 3000);
            }
        });
    });

    //  Cookie consent
    $('.sp-cookie-allow').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();               
        document.cookie = "spcookie_status=ok" + expires + "; path=/";

        $(this).closest('.sp-cookie-consent').fadeOut();
    });

    $(".btn-group label:not(.active)").click(function()
        {
            var label = $(this);
            var input = $('#' + label.attr('for'));
            
            if (!input.prop('checked')) {
                label.closest('.btn-group').find("label").removeClass('active btn-success btn-danger btn-primary');
                if (input.val() === '') {
                    label.addClass('active btn-primary');
                } else if (input.val() == 0) {
                    label.addClass('active btn-danger');
                } else {
                    label.addClass('active btn-success');
                }
                input.prop('checked', true);
                input.trigger('change');
            }
            var parent = $(this).parents('#attrib-helix_ultimate_blog_options'); 
            if( parent ){ 
                showCategoryItems( parent, input.val() )
            }
        });
        $(".btn-group input[checked=checked]").each(function()
        {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $("label[for=" + $(this).attr('id') + "]").addClass('active btn btn-primary');
            } else if ($(this).val() == 0) {
                $("label[for=" + $(this).attr('id') + "]").addClass('active btn btn-danger');
            } else {
                $("label[for=" + $(this).attr('id') + "]").addClass('active btn btn-success');
            }
            var parent = $(this).parents('#attrib-helix_ultimate_blog_options'); 
            if( parent ){
                parent.find('*[data-showon]').each( function() {
                    $(this).hide();
                })
            }
        });
        

        function showCategoryItems(parent, value){
            var controlGroup = parent.find('*[data-showon]'); 
            controlGroup.each( function() {
                var data = $(this).attr('data-showon')
                data = typeof data !== 'undefined' ? JSON.parse( data ) : []
                if( data.length > 0 ){
                    if(typeof data[0].values !== 'undefined' && data[0].values.includes( value )){
                        $(this).slideDown();
                    }else{
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        $(window).on('scroll', function(){
            var scrollBar = $(".sp-reading-progress-bar");
            if( scrollBar.length > 0 ){
                var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
                    d = $(document).height(),
                    c = $(window).height();
                var scrollPercent = (s / (d - c)) * 100;
                const postition = scrollBar.data('position')
                if( postition === 'top' ){
                    // var sticky = $('.header-sticky');
                    // if( sticky.length > 0 ){
                    //     sticky.css({ top: scrollBar.height() })
                    // }else{
                    //     sticky.css({ top: 0 })
                    // }
                }
                scrollBar.css({width: `${scrollPercent}%` })
            }
             
          })    

});
```

This is effectively commenting out the section and fixing the header bug, but it's also throwing the jQuery not defined error. Is there a more appropriate method for commenting out the section?

Note that the same error occurs if I simply delete the entire sticky header block.

Thank you from a newbie for any help!

Comment: remove `jQuery(function ($) {` and the `});` at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try single line comments for each line in the code block. If you have VS Code or similar IDE, then it should do it for you. Select all the lines and press CTRL + / or CMD + / (Mac).

```
    // if ($('body').hasClass('sticky-header')) {
    //     var header = $('#sp-header');

    //     if($('#sp-header').length) {
    //         var headerHeight = header.outerHeight();
    //         var stickyHeaderTop = header.offset().top;
    //         var stickyHeader = function () {
    //             var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    //             if (scrollTop > stickyHeaderTop) {
    //                 header.addClass('header-sticky');
    //             } else {
    //                 if (header.hasClass('header-sticky')) {
    //                     header.removeClass('header-sticky');
    //                 }
    //             }
    //         };
    //         stickyHeader();
    //         $(window).scroll(function () {
    //             stickyHeader();
    //         });
    //     }

    //     if ($('body').hasClass('layout-boxed')) {
    //         var windowWidth = header.parent().outerWidth();
    //         header.css({"max-width": windowWidth, "left": "auto"});
    //     }
    // }
```

Comment: Thank you, KD8581!